# Determine source of light in css linear gradient

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Based on two/three colors in linear gradient how can I determine on which side is the light source? Left or right? Which color has more 'lightness'?

Example where I tried to set light source to be on left:

```
const pallete = ['#f12711', '#f5af19'];

background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${pallete.sort((a, c) => chroma(a).luminance() - chroma(c).luminance()).join(',')})`
```

Thanks!

Comment: What library are you using for `chroma`?  Also, why do `.map(p => p)`?  Seems like a no-op.

Comment: chroma itself is a color library. I removed `map`, thanks.